# Bootstrap Confirmation data-on-confirm not executing function

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a delete confirmation execute a function that deletes the current id data.

I am getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

in this part of the `bootstrap-confirmation.js`

```
return function() {
  context[func].call(this);
};
```

this is my button code

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="confirmation" 
data-    btn-ok-    class="btn-danger" data-btn-cancel-icon="glyphicon 
glyphicon-ban-circle" data-btn-cancel-class="btn-default" 
data-popout="true" data-singleton="true" data-on-confirm="goDel(id)">
Eliminar</button>
```

this is my Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function goDel(id)
{
location.href="./delete/" + id;
}
</script>
```

this is my delete controller

```
public function delete($id) {
    $clientes = new Clientes();
    $codcta = new Codcta();
    $this -> codcta = $codcta -> find();
    $codciu = new Codciu();
    $this -> codciu = $codciu -> find();        
    $clientes = new clientes();
    if ($clientes->delete((int)$id)) {
            Flash::valid('El registro se ha eliminado correctamente');
    }else{
            Flash::error('Falló Operación'); 
    }
    return Redirect::to();
}
```

Comment: There is no such "bootstrap confirmation" javascript plugin on the bootstrap project and there are quite several plugins named "bootstrap-confirmation" on github. Which one are you using?

Comment: Also, I don't think the `data-on-confirm` attribute can receive and call a function that requieres input parameters since it wouldn't know what to pass to the `id` parameter. Better use a function that doesn't receive any parameters and try to get the `id` using any other strategy.

Comment: @RobertoLinares I'm using this plugin, will try your solution and let you know if it works [link](http://mistic100.github.io/Bootstrap-Confirmation/)

Comment: @RobertoLinares tried to implement a session variable and got the same error.

Comment: Can you update the source code on your question to reflect those changes? Also, a `session variable` is something stored on the server side of your application. All you are doing here occurs on the client without going to the server.

Comment: @RobertoLinares the problem seems to be happening when 'i call data-on-confirm="goDel(id)" ', still don't know how to get it to work.

Comment: @RobertoLinares solved the problem by adding a link on the button, don't know why but it worked.
<a class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="eliminar" data-on-confirm="goDel" data-btn-ok-class="btn-danger" data-btn-cancel-icon="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle" data-btn-cancel-class="btn-default" data-popout="true" data-singleton="true">
   Eliminar
   </a>

Comment: `don't know why but it worked` it worked because now you call the function without passing any parameters, which is the correct way to bind it to the `data-on-confirm` attribute, jeje.

Answer (score 8):

Change this in your button:

```
data-on-confirm="goDel"
```

and add this:

```
data-id="YOUR-ID-HERE"
```

in your javascript function:

```
function goDel()
{
    var id = $(this)[0].getAttribute('data-id');
    location.href="./delete/" + id;
}
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

### The button code in HTML will be:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="confirmation" data-title="Title here" data-content="Content here" data-btn-cancel-icon="glyphicon 
glyphicon-ban-circle" data-btn-cancel-class="btn-default" 
data-popout="true" data-singleton="true" data-on-confirm="deleteMethodName" data-id="your-deleted-id-here">Eliminar</button>
```

### The javascript function code will be:

```
function deleteMethodName()
{
    var id = $(this)[0].getAttribute('data-id');
    //Now you will get ID from above and use it as you like
}
```